# Why does GROUP BY HOUR(timestamp) return particular timestamp?

Tags: mysql, group-by, hour

**Question**: why query with GROUP BY HOUR(timestamp) function in following example returns usercount timestamp @ **2015-02-18 23:16:25** instead of, for example, first occurence @ **2015-02-18 23:14:12** ?

What is the mechanism inside MySQL that determines this choice?

---

Here is the result of a group by hour query:

```
mysql> SELECT *, COUNT(user_id) AS usercount FROM table_log WHERE user_id = 1 GROUP BY HOUR(timestamp) ORDER BY timestamp,usercount DESC;

+------+---------+-----------+---------------------+-----------+
| id   | user_id | user_name | timestamp           | usercount |
+------+---------+-----------+---------------------+-----------+
| 1013 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-16 00:51:32 |         2 |
| 1016 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-16 21:38:52 |         2 |
| 1018 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-17 02:05:44 |         3 |
| 1022 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 04:51:22 |         8 |
| 1001 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 23:16:25 |        22 |
| 1005 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-19 03:06:01 |         5 |
| 1009 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-19 05:15:32 |         3 |
| 1011 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-19 11:57:26 |         1 |
| 1012 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-19 12:09:20 |         1 |
+------+---------+-----------+---------------------+-----------+
9 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

And here is the result of a regular query (without grouping):

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM table_log WHERE user_id = 1 ORDER BY timestamp;

+------+---------+-----------+---------------------+
| id   | user_id | user_name | timestamp           |
+------+---------+-----------+---------------------+
| 1013 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-16 00:51:32 |
| 1014 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-16 00:51:38 |
| 1015 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-16 03:12:28 |
| 1016 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-16 21:38:52 |
| 1017 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-16 21:39:33 |
| 1018 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-17 02:05:44 |
| 1019 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-17 02:05:52 |
| 1020 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-17 02:05:55 |
| 1021 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-17 05:21:19 |
| 1022 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 04:51:22 |
| 1023 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 04:51:31 |
| 1024 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 04:51:35 |
| 1025 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 04:51:43 |
| 1026 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 04:51:46 |
| 1027 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 04:52:10 |
| 1028 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 04:52:24 |
| 1029 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 04:52:31 |
| 1030 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 23:14:12 |
| 1031 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 23:14:16 |
| 1032 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 23:14:53 |
| 1033 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 23:14:57 |
| 1034 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 23:14:59 |
| 1035 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 23:15:02 |
| 1036 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 23:15:05 |
| 1037 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 23:15:08 |
| 1038 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 23:15:10 |
| 1039 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 23:15:12 |
| 1040 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 23:15:13 |
| 1041 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 23:15:14 |
| 1042 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 23:15:24 |
| 1043 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 23:15:29 |
| 1044 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 23:15:39 |
| 1045 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 23:15:44 |
| 1046 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 23:16:15 |
| 1047 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 23:16:20 |
| 1001 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 23:16:25 |
| 1002 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 23:35:31 |
| 1003 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 23:47:20 |
| 1004 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-18 23:47:27 |
| 1005 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-19 03:06:01 |
| 1006 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-19 03:06:05 |
| 1007 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-19 03:06:11 |
| 1008 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-19 03:06:19 |
| 1009 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-19 05:15:32 |
| 1010 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-19 05:15:35 |
| 1011 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-19 11:57:26 |
| 1012 | 1       | 1         | 2015-02-19 12:09:20 |
+------+---------+-----------+---------------------+
47 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

NOTE: id column is AUTO INC + index

Comment: Is it the unique id column (lowest index first) ?

Comment: Because you have multiple values in the group and it pulls one out at random as a representative for the group. Standard SQL doesn't even let you do this. You need to say MIN(timestamp) if you want to retrieve the earliest one.

Comment: Also note that HOUR() is going to return a value from 0 to 23. So when your data is spread across multiple days it will still all fall within one of 24 diferent buckets.

Comment: thank you shawnt00, did not know about MIN() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the completeness of the Q/A, I'll repeat here what I already noticed in the comment section: id column (AUTO INC) is unique (index) and seems to be also taken into account when choosing the timestamp representative value. Apparently, the lowest first column id value spread across different days, but same hours, always 'wins' as a chosen timestamp value in group.

Comment: The `AUTO_INCREMENT` is not really a factor at all... except that MySQL happens to require that the column with AUTO_INCREMENT has to be in an **index**.  The observed behavior is due to the **order** in which MySQL retrieves the rows... in this particular case, MySQL happens to be using a particular index, likely, the table is InnoDB and the auto_increment column is the PRIMARY KEY. For completeness of the answer, we should really point out that the inferences/conclusions  drawn from this particular case do *not* hold true for the more general case.

Answer (score 1):

It's indeterminate *which* row will be returned. MySQL is free to return values from *any* row in the group.

Other databases will throw an exception with a query like this. But MySQL extends the functionality, and allows non-aggregates in the SELECT list.

The behavior is documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html

> MySQL extends the use of `GROUP BY` so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the `GROUP BY` clause. This means that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an `ORDER BY` clause. Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and `ORDER BY` does not affect which values within each group the server chooses.

Comment: Hi spencer7593, I will accept your answer, but I have also analysed the data (on a much larger scale) and it seems that column id (AUTO INC) is taken into account - the lowest index value is always used as a representative. Thanks!

Comment: @dev101: That may be the behavior you observe, but that behavior is *not* guaranteed. And I don't think it's really the AUTO_INCREMENT property that influences the behavior, rather, it's the *order* in which MySQL retrieves the rows... and that really depends on what *index* is used... in the case of an InnoDB table, the PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE INDEX is used as the cluster key. Likely, the AUTO_INCREMENT column is the PRIMARY KEY. If MySQL were to use a different index to access the rows, it's likely that the "first" row from the index (for the group) would be the one use. But again...

Comment: @dev101: ... this behavior is *not* guaranteed. If you need a particular row, use an aggregate expression... to get the lowest value e.g. use `MIN()`. If `sql_mode` includes `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, then MySQL will behave like other databases, and reject queries with non-aggregates in the select list that don't also appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Thank you spencer7593, column `id`  is primary key as well, so that might be it. I did not realise that key parameter was important in this case, would include it in the original question. How to use MIN() along the GROUP BY HOUR() in this particular query? If applied to timestamp, obviously it returns single timestamp for everything.